# Search filenames with GitLab API

Tags: gitlab

I'm using the GitLab API (http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/) to try to search for a specific file. I can successfully access a specific repository, but I was hoping to provide some text and retrieve any files that match the filename. If not that, then to at least get the full file structure of everything within the repository and do the search myself. Is this possible?

Comment: Isn't it as simple as calling GET /projects/:id/repository/files? See http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/repository_files.html.

Comment: No - I believe this only will give you information about a specific file, which you provide the file path for. I was looking for an entire listing of all files/folders within the repository.

Answer (score 3):

http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/repositories.html

I didnt skim through the full API docs, but a quick hack would be to list down the trees, you will get Gitlab ObjectifiedHash, run a loop and inside the loop put a condition saying if the type is a 'tree', then send its respective id again to fetch its tree and so on recursively and if its a blob, just save the name.

This way you get all the files/folder name. This is a bad way of doing it since you will do quite a few api calls. Read through the API docs fully.

I know this post is old, just answered anyway. Hope it helped

Answer (score 1):

There is an API for that, called "List repository tree". See the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repositories.html#list-repository-tree).

URL looks like this:

```
GET /projects/:id/repository/tree
```

You can specify the repository ref, the path (subdirectory) to get a listing for (default is the root of the repo), whether the listing is recursive (default is no), and the pagination parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I am using python-gitlab module which made searching for a file in repo easy
https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Get the "project" form module https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gl_objects/projects.html and then simply use this to read the file

```
try:
    f = project.files.get(file_path=filepath, ref=branch)
    return base64.b64decode(f.content)
except Exception as e:
    print e
    return ""
```